# Is there a better way to write this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created 3 stored procedures that will:

1. create a new db table
2. Insert data into the newly created table, insert a row into a log audit_log table and update an existing row in the same log audit_log table

Here is the order that I execute the stored procedures:

EXEC MKMG_Build_Appt_Table_Daily

EXEC MKMG_Build_Appt_Table_Daily_Insert

Everything works without any problems but is there a better way to accomplish this? If so, can you help with any suggestions and 
should there be any error handling added?

```
--Procedure 1
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MKMG_Build_Appt_Table] 
@TableName NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column1Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column1DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column2Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column2DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column3Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column3DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column4Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column4DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column5Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column5DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column6Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column6DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column7Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column7DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column8Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column8DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column9Name NVARCHAR(128)         ,@Column9DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column10Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column10DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column11Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column11DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column12Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column12DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column13Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column13DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column14Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column14DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column15Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column15DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column16Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column16DataType NVARCHAR(128)
,@Column17Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column17DataType NVARCHAR(128) 
,@Column18Name NVARCHAR(128)            ,@Column18DataType NVARCHAR(128) 

AS

   DECLARE @SQLString  NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE '+@TableName + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE()),112) + 

    '( '    + @Column1Name + ' '+ @Column1DataType + ','
            + @Column2Name + ' '+ @Column2DataType + ','
            + @Column3Name + ' '+ @Column3DataType + ','
            + @Column4Name + ' '+ @Column4DataType + ','
            + @Column5Name + ' '+ @Column5DataType + ','
            + @Column6Name + ' '+ @Column6DataType + ','
            + @Column7Name + ' '+ @Column7DataType + ','
            + @Column8Name + ' '+ @Column8DataType + ','
            + @Column9Name + ' '+ @Column9DataType + ','
            + @Column10Name + ' '+ @Column10DataType + ','
            + @Column11Name + ' '+ @Column11DataType + ','
            + @Column12Name + ' '+ @Column12DataType + ','
            + @Column13Name + ' '+ @Column13DataType + ','
            + @Column14Name + ' '+ @Column14DataType + ','
            + @Column15Name + ' '+ @Column15DataType + ','
            + @Column16Name + ' '+ @Column16DataType + ','
            + @Column17Name + ' '+ @Column17DataType + ','
            + @Column18Name + ' '+ @Column18DataType
    + ')'


    EXEC (@SQLString)


--Procedure 2

 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MKMG_Build_Appt_Table_Daily]
 AS

 EXEC MKMG_Build_Appt_Table 'downtime_appointments',
                            'person_id',        'uniqueidentifier',
                            'location_name',    'varchar(40)',
                            'appt_date',        'varchar(8)',
                            'begintime',        'char(4)',
                            'MRN',              'varchar(15)',
                            'patient',          'varchar(120)',
                            'age_years',        'varchar(3)',
                            'date_of_birth',    'varchar(8)',
                            'sex',              'char(1)',
                            'ethnicity',        'varchar(40)',
                            'language',         'varchar(100)',
                            'home_phone',       'varchar(10)',
                            'day_phone',        'varchar(20)',
                            'provider',         'varchar(75)',
                            'specialty',        'varchar(40)',
                            'event',            'varchar(30)',
                            'appt_type',        'char(1)',
                            'file_location',    'varchar(200)'


 --Procedure 3


 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MKMG_Build_Appt_Table_Daily_Insert]

 AS

    DECLARE @SQLString2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLString2 =   'INSERT INTO MUReports..downtime_appointments'+ '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE()),112) + ' ' +
                    'SELECT * FROM MUReports..downtime_appointments'

    EXEC (@SQLString2)


    INSERT INTO MUReports..downtime_appointments_audit_log 
    VALUES('downtime_appointments'+ '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)      + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE()),112), 'Y', GETDATE()) 

    UPDATE MUReports..downtime_appointments_audit_log SET status = 'N' 
    WHERE appt_table_name = 'downtime_appointments' + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()),112) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112)



 --Audit_log

 CREATE TABLE downtime_appointments_audit_log (
 appt_table_name        VARCHAR(100),
 status             VARCHAR(1),
 time_stamp         DATETIME
 )




 --downtime_appointments table


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[downtime_appointments](
[person_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[location_name] [varchar](40) NULL,
[appt_date] [varchar](8) NULL,
[begintime] [char](4) NULL,
[MRN] [varchar](15) NULL,
[patient] [varchar](120) NULL,
[age_years] [varchar](3) NULL,
[date_of_birth] [varchar](8) NULL,
[sex] [char](1) NULL,
[ethnicity] [varchar](40) NULL,
[language] [varchar](100) NULL,
[home_phone] [varchar](10) NULL,
[day_phone] [varchar](10) NULL,
[provider] [varchar](75) NULL,
[specialty] [varchar](40) NULL,
[event] [varchar](30) NULL,
[appt_type] [char](1) NULL,
[file_location] [varchar](200) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: IMO MKMG_Build_Appt_Table provides zero value and only adds complexity and fragility. Maybe make the table name getting a function but that's all I would do there.

Comment: Whenever you start naming tables with things like the date in them it should be a HUGE red flag that something is very wrong. And that downtime_appointments tables seems to have pretty serious normalization issues going on. You seem to have a foreign key to a person table but then there is data for a person in the appointments table. dates as varchar, storing a person's age (this should be calculated), etc.

Comment: Then you have the issue of primary keys. The way you have this all your tables will be heaps. And honestly, what is the point? You have to provide every column name and datatype anyway. Why not just write a create table statement and forget a procedure to create a table. It has lots of headaches and is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: The table have always the same structure?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your simulation of partitioning isn't good idea.
2. If you would like store historical data or changes you should use for example trigger (with timestamp and dml type).
3. If you would like to create table with the same structure the easiest way is

   ```
   select top 0 * into newtable from oldtable
   ```
4. Use appropriate property for table columns (NULL vs NOT NULL), constraints and indexes. Date as varchar is ok (it's ISO 8601 date format), but no if it could be combinated with time. But date as varchar(8) and time as char(4) - try to design uniformly.
5. Yes, your code should have error handling, especialy when you use dynamical statements.
6. Avoid duplicate composing of names - it should be in variable.